# Custom AlertDialog with a List

Tags: android, user-interface, android-alertdialog

[image: AlertDialog with list]

I want to create this exactly AlertDialog, but I didn't know how to do it, How to change the typeface for the selected item and How to add this icon on the right for the selected item too

Answer (score 0):

You can make dialog like this and set Id for it whenever you clicking any text that clickable text's Id is store in that Id's variable and do another thing set icon with boolean.

like,
if your position is matched with Id then icon will visible else it will invisible